# How to change the compile order of LESS CSS compiler

Tags: css, less

is there a way to influence the less compiler in which order the less files are compiled?

i have a less file containint color settings and variables (settings.less) and a bunch of other less files which use the variables from settings.less.

Is there a way to use the settings.less inside the other less files without importing them within these files?

Maybe it will help to influence the order in which the less files are compiled? Compiling the settings.less as the first file so that the compiler has all the variables in memory? Is there a way to achieve that? It seems like the default compiler compiles the files in  aplhabetical order.

Comment: Why not just include the required files?

Comment: +1 @JuanMendes That's the way to go. That way, less compiler will compile all your files in the correct order, and you'll get only one css file which will also load faster.

Comment: i want to create a color theme based on the values from the settings.less without copying ALL files.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in C, Java, and others, you have to include/import dependencies from the file itself